# Ecmascript 6 class in Webstorm 10

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, phpstorm, webstorm, es6-class

I use webstorm 10, and was trying ecmascript 6 with the following code:

```
/**
 * Class Person
 */
class Person {
    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param lastname
     * @param firstname
     * @param age
     * @param sexe
     */
    constructor(lastname, firstname, age, sexe) {
        this.lastname  = lastname;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.age       = age;
        this.sexe      = sexe;
    }

    /**
     * Return the name as string
     * @returns {string}
     */
    toString() {
        return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname;
    }

    /**
     * Return true if is an Adult
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    isAdult() {
        return this.age > 18;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param {Person} person
     * @returns {*}
     */
    static isAdult(person) {
        return person.isAdult();
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong that webstorm tell me that firstname and lastname in toString are unresolved variables, so age and as well isAdult() in the static method?

Comment: does it support ecma6? sounds like it's reading it as ecma5. add "function " before "toString" and if that makes the complaint go away,  you know it has no idea what ES6 is supposed to look like...

Comment: Have you set the language version to ES6: File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Javascript.  There is a video on YouTube showing how to configure Webstorm with Traceur that includes all this info., though having said that there is now a Babel plugin available as well.  I'd add also that ES6 is still not a standard, only a draft, Webstorm currently supports a fair amount of this standard, but still has quite a few features to implement.

Comment: Ok guys thanks for your answer I have the IDE set correctly as for jshint option. What I forgot to say is I created the file as scratch using as well the options ecma6... I created a real file with the same content and it works it seems that only the scratch function failing...

Comment: By the way. I am looking babel, great compiler. And I am really looking really forward to use ecma 6... As well if know I am just playing with it...

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into the same problem. In order to fix it you have to supply the `@class` annotation. This way, it knows it's a class and treats properties as class properties, without warnings.

```
/**
 * @class Person
 */
class Person {
    ...
```

You might also want to annotate the properties, like so

```
/**
 * @class Person
 * @property lastname {String}
 * @property firstname {String}
 * @property age {Number}
 * @property sexe {String}
 */
```